# Yii Ajax Update depending dropdown selection

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have dropdown list where there are five or six items (here items are services). I used here ajax request which updates the id “package_id” from the URL `'url'=>$this->createUrl('servicePackage'),` once I select any service item. Till now, I have done successfully. But I want that ajax should use different URL and update different id i.e. “registrationid” if I select 4th number item, otherwise it should update “package_id”. 
Is it possible?

Is it possible?

The form is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'service_id', array('class' => 'control-label col-lg-4')); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'service_id',CHtml::listData(Service::model()->findAll(),'id', 'name'),
    array(
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'prompt'=>'Select a Service',
        'ajax' => array('type'=>'POST',
            'url'=>$this->createUrl('servicePackage'), 
            'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'package_id'), // ajax updates package_id, but I want ajax update registration_id if I select item no 4
            'data'=>array('service_id'=>'js:this.value'),
        )));
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'service_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="packageid">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'package_id', array('class' => 'control-label col-lg-4')); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
    <?php
    echo $form->dropDownList($model,'package_id',$model->getServicePackage($model->service_id),array(
        'class' => 'form-control','prompt'=>'Select a Package',
        'ajax' =>
        array('type'=>'POST',
            'url'=>$this->createUrl('packagePrice'), //url to call.
            'update'=>'#price', //selector to update
            'data'=>array('package_id'=>'js:this.value'),
        )));
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'package_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="registrationid">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'registration_id', array('class' => 'control-label col-lg-4')); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php
        $registrants = Registration::model()->findAll();
        $data = CHtml::listData($registrants,'id', function($registrants) {
            return CHtml::encode($registrants->name.' ('.$registrants->id.')');
        });
        echo $form->dropDownList($model,'registration_id',$data,
            array(
                'class' => 'required form-control chzn-select',
                'prompt'=>'Select a Registrant',
                'ajax' => array('type'=>'POST',
                    'url'=>$this->createUrl('Order'), //url to call.
                    'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'order_id'), //selector to update
                    'data'=>array('registration_id'=>'js:this.value'),
                )

            ));
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'registration_id'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should keep an array of urls, an depending on your situation, select from it

Comment: thanks @tereško please could you help me how to do it.

Comment: @tinyByte please help me how to code it?

Comment: @tereško please could you help me how to do this or give an example what I can follow